# Overwrite HTTP REFERER with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, http-referer

I am trying to overwrite custom value to HTTP REFERRER. I got success with javascript but my client want in PHP and i need help in rewriting Javascript to PHP.

JS code :

```js
var reff = ["http://example.com", "http://example.net", "http://example.org"];
var randomreff = reff[Math.floor(Math.random() * reff.length)];
delete window.document.referrer;
window.document.__defineGetter__("referrer", function () {
  return randomreff;
});

document.write(document.referrer);
```

I am trying to rewrite this code in PHP or maybe finding a similar solution with PHP. i tried multiple way to do in PHP. these are some example.

PHP Try 1 :

```
$reff = new Arr("http://example.com", "http://example.net", "http://example.org");
$randomreff = get($reff, call_method($Math, "floor", to_number(call_method($Math, "random")) * to_number(get($reff, "length"))));
_delete(get($window, "document"), "referrer");
call_method(get($window, "document"), "__defineGetter__", "referrer", new Func(function() use (&$randomreff) {
  return $randomreff;
}));
```

PHP with variable :

```
$var = 'var reff = ["http://example.com", "http://example.net", "http://example.org"];
var randomreff = reff[Math.floor(Math.random() * reff.length)];
delete window.document.referrer;
window.document.__defineGetter__("referrer", function () {
  return randomreff;
});
';
```

PHP with header referer :

```
header("Referer: https://www.example.com/");
```

None of them worked. Help me to rewrite Javascript code or alternative solution with PHP.

Comment: How would PHP on the client work or JS on the server in a PHP process work? I would expect only the header to work

Comment: @mplungjan i know PHP is server-end but i found on google. it possible to pass custom value to HTTP Referer with PHP too but i do not get a working solution how

Comment: @freedomn-m using `$refer = "http://example.com"` will not change the HTTP REFERER Request.

Comment: @freedomn-m to change the referer for some affiliate & advertising purpose

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do this with PHP exclusively. `document.referrer` is a DOM property that is set by the browser when the page loads by reading the referrer header on the request. Since the request is generated by the browser you can't really touch it with PHP since that is executed on the server and not in the browser, if you want to execute something in the browser you will need javascript.

In your examples you are just trying to run javascript-code from PHP it seems, and that just won't work. The last sample that sets the `referrer`-header will set it on the response back from the server, but as I said, referrer is a request variable so it will just be ignored.

The only thing you could do from PHP is to tell the browser to redirect to the page again (by setting the `location`-header), but as far as I know these days this won't reset the `referral`-header (if so then redirects from http to https for example would loose it all the time).

I'm not exactly sure are you trying to acomplish here. Setting `document.referrer` is only valid for the current page and won't affect what the next page sees. If executed early it might fool some tracking scripts at most.